# Number to utf-8 unicode converting using php

Tags: php, string, utf-8

Actually my expected result was-
zero ০
one ১
two ২
three ৩
four ৪
five ৫
six ৬
seven ৭
eight ৮
nine ৯

But I got-
zero &#ý৯;ý৯;3৭;৬;ý৯;ý৯;3৭;ý৯;3৮;;
     one &#ý৯;ý৯;3৭;৬;ý৯;ý৯;3৭;ý৯;;
     two ý৯;ý৯;3৭;৬;
     three ý৯;3৭;
     four ý৯;3৮;
     five ý৯;
     six ৬
     seven ৭
     eight ৮
     nine ৯
pleas help me.
The code:

```
$n=array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');

 $x=array("&#2534;", "&#2535;", "&#2536;", "&#2537;", "&#2538;", "&#2539;", "&#2540;", "&#2541;", "&#2542;", "&#2543;");

$on='O 0
 one 1
 two 2
 three 3
 four 4
 five 5
 six 6
 seven 7
 eight 8
 nine 9';

 $converted = nl2br(str_replace($n, $x, $on));


 echo $converted;
```

Comment: why not serve your page with a content-type encoding of UTF-8 and use the actual characters instead of the entities?

Comment: Sorry content type utf-8 is not the solution.

Comment: I've added <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8;"> in <head> but the same result returned.

Comment: meta tags are only used then server does not serve appropriate headers. Either set the content via php.net/headers or check your webserver configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` is not encoding-safe. you have an implementation of a multibyte `str_replace` ( `mb_str_replace` ) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) :

```
function mb_str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack)
{
    $needle_len = mb_strlen($needle);
    $replacement_len = mb_strlen($replacement);
    $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle);
    while ($pos !== false)
    {
        $haystack = mb_substr($haystack, 0, $pos) . $replacement
                . mb_substr($haystack, $pos + $needle_len);
        $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos + $replacement_len);
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

**Edit:** Oups, your characters are HTML encoded, not a PHP encoding problem.

Comment: Sorry it's not working in array. Can you provide me to use in case of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The function you want to use for this purpose is [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

```
$x = array("&#2534;", "&#2535;", "&#2536;", "&#2537;", "&#2538;", "&#2539;", "&#2540;", "&#2541;", "&#2542;", "&#2543;");
$converted = nl2br(strtr($on, $x));
echo $converted;
```

which produces the following:

> O ০
>   one ১
>   two ২
>   three
>   ৩
>   four ৪
>   five ৫
>   six ৬
>   seven ৭
>   eight ৮
>   nine ৯

str_replace() doesn't work here because the latter entries in the array is replacing characters in the replacement done by earlier entries.

P.S. The array really ought to be an associative array (i.e. "0" => "০"). I was too lazy to make the change and just use the fact that the integer keys happen to be right.